# button disappears when i clicked it

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

When I click `button1`, I want it to disappear and `button2` and `button3` appear. When I click `button3`, I want it to go back to page that `button1` is displayed. I was trying based on this code, but I can't make it. please help.

My HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="button1" value="button">
        button1-t
    </button>

    <button id="button2" value="new tab" style="display: none;">
        button2-t
    </button>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#button1').on('click', function () {
        $('#button2').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: you can also use attribute hidden instead of inline style="display:none;". This makes the code cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go with the "hidden" attribute.

HTML code

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="button1" value="button">
        button1-t
    </button>

    <button id="button2" value="new tab" hidden>
        button2-t
    </button>
</div>
```

JS code

```
$(function () {
 $('#button1').on('click', function () {
    $('#button2').removeAttr("hidden");
    $("#button1").attr("hidden", true);
 });

 $('#button2').on('click', function () {
    $('#button1').removeAttr("hidden");
    $("#button2").attr("hidden", true);
 });
});
```